# lists set off by parentheses

Tags: parentheses

Do parenthetical lists need "e.g." preceding the list, such as:
"I am building a model of the house with key attributes (height, style, color) considered for comparison with other development areas."

Answer (score 2):

Both *i.e.* and *e.g.* can be used to distinguish types of lists and examples but they are not strictly necessary.

In your example, the advantage of using *e.g.* would be to clearly signal that there are more attributes than what was listed. Another way of doing this is using *etc.* but you should never use *e.g.* and *etc.* in the same list.

> I am building a model of the house with key attributes (e.g. height, style, color) considered for comparison with other development areas.
>
> I am building a model of the house with key attributes (height, style, color, etc.) considered for comparison with other development areas.

If height, style and color actually *are* the only attributes then it would be inappropriate to use *e.g.* or *etc.* and the sentence as written is the best choice.

Comment: I prefer using a comma after e.g., and in your first example, I'd also put an "and" after "style":  "I am building a model of the house with key attributes (e.g., height, style, and color) considered for comparison with other development areas."  Am I being a punctuation Nazi?

Comment: Yes, you are being a punctuation Nazi. "(e.g. height, style, color)" is perfectly valid. [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.g.#e.g.) only note is that it is sometimes followed by a comma.

Comment: Mea culpa.  Mea maxima culpa.  It's always good to have options.  Don.  P.S. Sieg heil!